# Assigning private members values through public functions in C++

Tags: c++

I have a bit of confusion on assigning private members value in C++.
As far as I think both of the following ways of setting length and breadth should work. What is the difference and is one way correct?

```
class Box
{
   public:
      void setlength(double len)
      {
         length = len;
      }
      void setbreadth(double bread)
      {
         this->breadth = bread;
      }
   private:
      double length;     // Length of a box
      double breadth;    // Breadth of a box
};
```

Comment: Many ppl have same variable names for the local ones and the member variables. In such cases, this helps to differentiate. For example, instead of len, I can have length as the name of the local var and have `this->length = length`. Especially when the variable name is long like isFileDeltedFromRootFolder. I dont want to create a new variable name for the same purpose

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply. so i am not being paranoid of doing something wrong :)

Answer (score 4):

Both are correct. Within the body of class member functions, all class members are in scope. The `this->` is implicit. So while `this->breadth` explicitly accesses the `breadth` member, `length` in `setlength()` implicitly accesses `this->length`.

Explicit access would allow you to use the same name for the argument and the member:

```
void setBreadth(double breadth) {
    this->breadth = breadth;
}
```

In this case, the *unqualified* access refers to the argument and the *qualified* access refers to the member.

Comment: thanks for the reply. makes it clearer with implicit and explicit access. so in the example here, by unqualified access you mean `double breadth` is treated as a local variable and `this->breadth` is the actual access to the private member?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. It is syntactic sugar.

Comment: It's not "syntactic sugar."

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069064/barry)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36779047/1413395) I personally prefer to write something like

```
class Box
{
   public:
      double length() const { return length_; }
      void length(double length) { length_ = length; }
      double breadth() const { return breadth_; }
      void breadth(double breadth) { breadth_ = breadth; }
   private:
      double length_;     // Length of a box
      double breadth_;    // Breadth of a box
};
```

to avoid ambiguities and have concise getter/setter function names based on overloads.

Comment: what does the `const` do in the function definition there ?

Comment: never mind, I checked in other source. thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `this` pointer is not necessary if the member- and parameter names are different. 
It's an explicit way of saying *member of this object*, whose value is the address of the object.

But, if you don't use the `this` pointer when the names are *equal*, you will be assigning the value of the local variable to itself:

```
void setlength(double length) 
{ // assigning value to itself
    length = length;
} // this->length is unchanged
```

If the names are the same and you use the `this` pointer explicitly, you will get the expected result:

```
void setlength(double length) 
{
    this->length = length;
}
```

Here we are saying *I mean length that belongs to **this** object*

Answer (score -1):

Barry explained briefly. `length = len;`, its actually acting the same as `this->length = len;` because class methods have a hidden parameter called `this` and `this` is implicitly inserted.